# PHP File operation, skip empty lines

Tags: php

I have a txt file generated by an instrument. The file needs some sanitation before the data is read into a mysql table. I have done this. But now due to some problem the data generated by the instruments contains empty lines in between and I want to remove it.

At present this is the code

```
 $target=$_FILES["report_file"]["tmp_name"];        
$file_contents = file_get_contents($target);
$file_contents = str_replace("?","",$file_contents);
$file_contents = str_replace(" ","",$file_contents);
$file_contents = str_replace("","",$file_contents);
$file_contents = str_replace("~","",$file_contents);
$file_contents = str_replace("","",$file_contents);
$file_contents = str_replace("#","",$file_contents);
$file_contents = str_replace(","," ",$file_contents);


file_put_contents($target,$file_contents);

$f = fopen($target, "r");
```

Can I use file_skip_empty_lines with file_put_contents? of how to put contents without empty lines?

Comment: is it a CSV format file?  Where is the code after `$f = fopen($target, "r");`  you can skip them when you read it, I'd be careful changing the file or you may wind up with something that is unreadable. especially using this `file_put_contents`, imagine stripping all the line returns from your file then over-writing it, bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim empty lines using `preg_replace`

Trim whitespaces at the beginning of line

```
$file_contents = preg_replace("!^s+!m", "", $file_contents);
```

Remove empty lines

```
$file_contents = preg_replace("![\n\r]+\s*[\n\r]+!", "\r\n", $file_contents);
```

Comment: Whether it will also remove carriage returns? I need Carriage return in each line

Comment: If you need to preserve `Carriage return` add `\r` to replace string, I updated answer

Comment: Now there is one more issue. There is a white space in the beginning of each line. I tried  $file_contents = str_replace(" ","",$file_contents), but it is not working.